# Updating Paging 3 alpha to stable cause indexing issue Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

Hey I am using **Paging 3** library with **ViewPager 2**. In which it loads unlimited data.

```
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha07"
```

**DataSource.kt**

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample

import java.util.*

class DataSource(
    private val size: Int = 5,
    private val currentDate: Date,
    private val limitDate: Date?
) {

    fun returnData(pageNumber: Int): List<Date> {

        val dateList = mutableListOf<Date>()
        val startDateForPage = startDate(pageNumber)
        val tempCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        tempCalendar.time = startDateForPage
        val lastDateForPage = endDate(startDateForPage)

        while (tempCalendar.time < lastDateForPage) {
            if (limitDate == null ||
                tempCalendar.time.before(limitDate) ||
                tempCalendar.time == limitDate
            ) {
                dateList.add(tempCalendar.time)
                tempCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        return dateList
    }

    private fun startDate(pageNumber: Int): Date {
        if (pageNumber == 0) {
            return currentDate
        } else {
            Calendar.getInstance().let {
                it.time = currentDate
                it.add(Calendar.DATE, pageNumber * size)
                return it.time
            }
        }
    }

    private fun endDate(firstDateForPage: Date): Date {
        Calendar.getInstance().let {
            it.time = firstDateForPage
            it.add(Calendar.DATE, size)
            return it.time
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerPagingSource.kt**

```
class ViewPagerPagingSource(
    private val dataSource: DataSource
) : PagingSource<Int, Date>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Date> {
        val position = params.key ?: 0

        return try {
            val data = dataSource.returnData(position)
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = data,
                prevKey = if (data.isEmpty()) null else position - 1,
                nextKey = if (data.isEmpty()) null else position + 1,
                itemsBefore = LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED,
                itemsAfter = LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED
            )
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }

}
```

All code working fine. when application starts it loads current date page.

[image]

Now when I am updating the library to this version

```
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.1"
```

It jumping to **-1** page I guess and look like this

[image]

I don't understand why this is causing the issue and also i edited **ViewPagerPagingSource** to implement another method

```
override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Date>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition
}
```

I don't understand what is causing the issue after updating the library. I am adding my github repository [Example](https://github.com/vivek-modi/ViewPagerExample). Please someone suggest me what is going wrong in code?

**UPDATE**

I tried to learn the paging concept and update my code. Also, do changes as per @dlam suggestion.

Again is jumping 1 page if I pass few days before date as current date. [Github](https://github.com/vivek-modi/ViewPagerExample)

```
2021-11-21 21:20:40.820 5460-5460/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page -1: [06/11/2021, 07/11/2021, 08/11/2021, 09/11/2021, 10/11/2021]
2021-11-21 21:20:40.821 5460-5460/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 0: [11/11/2021, 12/11/2021, 13/11/2021, 14/11/2021, 15/11/2021]
2021-11-21 21:20:40.821 5460-5460/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 1: [16/11/2021, 17/11/2021, 18/11/2021, 19/11/2021, 20/11/2021]
```

UPDATE 2

After @MuhannadFakhouri answer I tried this logic

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample

import java.util.*

class DataSource(
    private val size: Int = 5,
    private val currentDate: Date,
    private val limitDate: Date? = null
) {

    fun returnData(pageNumber: Int): Result {
        val dateList = mutableListOf<Date>()

        val startDateForPage = startDate(pageNumber)
        val tempCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        tempCalendar.time = startDateForPage
        val lastDateForPage = endDate(startDateForPage)

        var index = size
        while (tempCalendar.time <= lastDateForPage && index-- > 0) {
            dateList.add(tempCalendar.time)
            tempCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
        val limitCalendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply { limitDate }
        return Result(
            result = dateList,
            pageNumber - 1,
            if (dateList.lastOrNull()?.let { Calendar.getInstance().apply { time = it } }
                    ?.let {
                        it.get(Calendar.YEAR) == limitCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                                it.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == limitCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
                    } == true)
                null
            else
                pageNumber + 1
        )
    }

    private fun startDate(pageNumber: Int): Date {
        Calendar.getInstance().let {
            it.time = currentDate
            it.add(Calendar.DATE, pageNumber * size)
            return it.time
        }
    }

    private fun endDate(firstDateForPage: Date): Date? {
        Calendar.getInstance().let {
            it.time = firstDateForPage
            it.add(Calendar.DATE, size)

            limitDate?.let { limit ->
                return if (it.time > limit) limit else it.time
            } ?: run {
                return it.time
            }
        }
    }

    data class Result(
        val result: MutableList<Date>,
        val prevKey: Int?,
        val nextKey: Int?
    )
}
```

**Logs**

```
2022-01-08 23:39:12.601 7886-7886/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page -1: [24/12/2021, 25/12/2021, 26/12/2021, 27/12/2021, 28/12/2021]
2022-01-08 23:39:12.603 7886-7886/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 0: [29/12/2021, 30/12/2021, 31/12/2021, 01/01/2022, 02/01/2022]
2022-01-08 23:39:12.604 7886-7886/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 1: [03/01/2022, 04/01/2022, 05/01/2022, 06/01/2022, 07/01/2022]
```

ScreenShot

[image]

It need to show **29/12/2021** date but it showing me **03/01/2022**

**NEW EXPLANATION IN DETAILS**

[Youtube Link with detail explanination](https://youtu.be/wA0artXVE2Q)

First It opens screens in which only one button. when I click on this it will open viewpager screen. Whenever I click it opening different date screen. My main point is If I pass as **current date** it will open for **current date** as view pager main screen. If I pass any date for example **29/12/2021** so it will open this date. The new attached video is showing how it behaving. It will show the code, logs and emulator.

**First time** when I clicked it open **04/01/22** which is index **-1** you can check in video

```
2022-01-09 00:01:03.108 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page -1: [04/01/2022, 05/01/2022, 06/01/2022, 07/01/2022, 08/01/2022]
2022-01-09 00:01:03.109 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 0: [09/01/2022]
2022-01-09 00:01:03.109 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 1: []
```

**Second time** it happens same

```
2022-01-09 00:01:06.488 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page -1: [04/01/2022, 05/01/2022, 06/01/2022, 07/01/2022, 08/01/2022]
2022-01-09 00:01:06.488 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 0: [09/01/2022]
2022-01-09 00:01:06.488 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 1: []
```

**Third time** It opens **09/01/22** which it correct.

```
2022-01-09 00:01:09.181 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page -1: [04/01/2022, 05/01/2022, 06/01/2022, 07/01/2022, 08/01/2022]
2022-01-09 00:01:09.181 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 0: [09/01/2022]
2022-01-09 00:01:09.181 9637-9637/com.example.viewpagerexample E/Page 1: []
```

My question is this why is this causing this kind of issue sometimes open correct **index** and sometime it will open wrong **index**.

Thanks

Logs

```
2022-01-09 14:15:25.501 21246-21246/com.example.viewpagerexample D/Debugging paging: load: null java.lang.Throwable
        at com.example.viewpagerexample.ViewPagerPagingSource.load(ViewPagerPagingSource.kt:16)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.doInitialLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:283)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.access$doInitialLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:54)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$pageEventFlow$1.invokeSuspend(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:163)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$pageEventFlow$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$pageEventFlow$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at androidx.paging.CancelableChannelFlowKt$cancelableChannelFlow$1.invokeSuspend(CancelableChannelFlow.kt:30)
        at androidx.paging.CancelableChannelFlowKt$cancelableChannelFlow$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.paging.CancelableChannelFlowKt$cancelableChannelFlow$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at androidx.paging.SimpleChannelFlowKt$simpleChannelFlow$1$1$producer$1$1.invokeSuspend(SimpleChannelFlow.kt:57)
        at androidx.paging.SimpleChannelFlowKt$simpleChannelFlow$1$1$producer$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.paging.SimpleChannelFlowKt$simpleChannelFlow$1$1$producer$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:264)
        at androidx.paging.SimpleChannelFlowKt$simpleChannelFlow$1$1$producer$1.invokeSuspend(SimpleChannelFlow.kt:52)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:375)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith$default(DispatchedContinuation.kt:278)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedCoroutine.afterResume(Builders.common.kt:256)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:102)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2022-01-09 14:15:25.512 21246-21246/com.example.viewpagerexample D/Debugging paging: load: -1 java.lang.Throwable
        at com.example.viewpagerexample.ViewPagerPagingSource.load(ViewPagerPagingSource.kt:16)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.doLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:406)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.access$doLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:54)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$collectAsGenerationalViewportHints$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:135)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:62)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:244)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharedFlowImpl.tryEmit(SharedFlow.kt:368)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler$HintFlow.setValue(HintHandler.kt:133)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler$processHint$1.invoke(HintHandler.kt:85)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler$processHint$1.invoke(HintHandler.kt:79)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler$State.modify(HintHandler.kt:119)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler.processHint(HintHandler.kt:79)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.accessHint(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:197)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcher$PagerUiReceiver.accessHint(PageFetcher.kt:215)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(PagingDataDiffer.kt:175)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2022-01-09 14:15:25.519 21246-21246/com.example.viewpagerexample D/Debugging paging: load: -2 java.lang.Throwable
        at com.example.viewpagerexample.ViewPagerPagingSource.load(ViewPagerPagingSource.kt:16)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.doLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:406)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.access$doLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:54)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$collectAsGenerationalViewportHints$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:135)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:62)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:244)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharedFlowImpl.tryEmit(SharedFlow.kt:368)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler$HintFlow.setValue(HintHandler.kt:133)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler$processHint$1.invoke(HintHandler.kt:85)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler$processHint$1.invoke(HintHandler.kt:79)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler$State.modify(HintHandler.kt:119)
        at androidx.paging.HintHandler.processHint(HintHandler.kt:79)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.accessHint(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:197)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcher$PagerUiReceiver.accessHint(PageFetcher.kt:215)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer.get(PagingDataDiffer.kt:271)
        at androidx.paging.AsyncPagingDataDiffer.getItem(AsyncPagingDataDiffer.kt:214)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataAdapter.getItem(PagingDataAdapter.kt:231)
        at com.example.viewpagerexample.ViewPagerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ViewPagerAdapter.kt:11)
        at com.example.viewpagerexample.ViewPagerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ViewPagerAdapter.kt:8)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873
```

Comment: I don't know Paging well enough to see if you're doing something wrong, try [creating an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=413106) on Google issue tracker. For now you can use the version which is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you filed a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/204328119, but I also wanted to update this answer for other future people reading this issue on SO.

The core issue is that you are starting collection on Paging before ViewPager is ready to start binding this items. You should use `lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated` instead of `lifecycleScope.launch` to fix this:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
  viewModel.dataList.collectLatest {
    adapter.submitData(it)
  }
}
```

The other issue I noticed (which would also workaround this), is that you have placeholders enabled, but aren't passing in `itemsBefore` or `itemsAfter` in `LoadResult.Page`. Enabling placeholders and having a static count would also give your view a list size to bind, but since you pass `COUNT_UNDEFINED`, Paging is not able to pad the list with `null` placeholders properly since it has no idea how many to add.

Comment: what can I pass the value in `itemBefore` or `itemAfrer` ?

Comment: You just pass the `Int` number of items before and after that page in `LoadResult.Page`'s constructor. For example if you have [null, null, 3, null], you would pass 2 for `itemsBefore` and 1 for `itemsAfter` in a `Page` whose `data` contains only `3`.

Comment: I tried to learn paging logic and tried to update my logic and still it causing this same issue [Github](https://github.com/vivek-modi/ViewPagerExample).

Comment: In my `ViewPagerViewModel` I create two functions `currentDate` in which I am passing a few days before the date from the current date. It again causing the same issue to start from index 1. But if I pass current date it working fine in `limitDate`. Do you know why this is causing this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't look in-deep into this and how this can be related to library's version, but i noticed a glitch in your Datasource logic
you're doing the following check

```
                if (lastDateForPage == limitDate)
                    null
                else
                    pageNumber + 1
```

after this loop

```
        while (tempCalendar.time <= lastDateForPage && index-- > 0) {
            dateList.add(tempCalendar.time)
            tempCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
```

the loop might actually break without the limit getting reached, this means your datasource doesn't guarantee that limitDate is always reached.

Changing the condition `lastDateForPage == limitDate` to check on the following, should fix the issue

```
            val limitCalendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply { limitDate }

            if (dateList.lastOrNull()?.let { Calendar.getInstance().apply { time = it } }
                    ?.let {
                        it.get(Calendar.YEAR) == limitCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                                it.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == limitCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
                    } == true)
                null
            else
                pageNumber + 1
```

Comment: I tried your code it's not working it giving wrong date :(

Comment: Then i need you to describe the usecase you're trying to achieve, so that i can understand the problem you're facing

Comment: I need to show as date in my current page viewpager. If I pass date as `29/11/2021` it need to start screen with this date. But right now it taking wrong index.

Comment: I added new explanation in details section with YouTube link please have a look. If any doubt please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, anyways lets assume that there's no problem with your datasource, add thislog statement `Log.d("Debugging paging", "load: ${params.key} ${Throwable().stackTraceToString()}")` to your `ViewPagerPagingSource.load`  and post its output

Comment: I added the output. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: you need to run fast so many times in your device. Press button and go back to previous screen and so and so.