# Could not get unknown property 'implementation' for object of type Dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-library

Hello there after adding dependency of paging

```
val paging_version = "3.1.0"

implementation("androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version")
```

I'm getting this error

```
Could not set unknown property 'paging_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

> Note: I have switched my project from java to kotlin ( because there
> is some issue the entire project cant be converted so I convert every
> java file one by one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added it like this and it works:

```
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.0'
```

Comment: just want to ask something, i have recently converted my java project into kotlin , but because the entire project is not converting at the same time I converted individual java files to kotlin , is there any way to implement all the kotlin project structure to my project , because I'm facing some issues , one after another

Comment: and because I'm very beginner i don't know what things are important in kotlin that has to be added

Comment: Mate its been 2 years I have swithed from Java to Kotlin. Kotlin is so much better! I do not know... Just learn from the beginning Kotlin it worth it :)

Comment: YUp, but I think you didn't understand my question properly, for eg if we create a kotlin project there will be some files that are specific to kotlin projects, now as my project was java and I converted individual files to kotlin , there will be probably some files that may be missing for a kotlin project, like Java folder should be Kotlin, etc

Comment: so is there any way that i can convert my project properly to a kotlin project

Comment: Hi, this is a big discussion. And there is not one answer to your question. It depends is the answer. Keep in mind that android studio's kotlin project can compile java also. You do not have to convert everything to kotlin.

Comment: @F.Mysir can you please see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69755212/11560810)

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 different kinds of migrating to kotlin for android projects.

What you did is migrate your code from java to kotlin. This is what people usually mean when they want to migrate their project to kotlin.

This by itself doesn't change the gradle file to kotlin. The code you tried is applying kotlin to the gradle file. It is possible to change to kotlin (instead of groovy, which you probably have now) but that's a different process.

The groovy equivalent of

```
val paging_version = "3.1.0"

implementation("androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version")
```

would be

```
def paging_version = "3.1.0"

implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:${paging_version}"
```

Comment: can you please see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69755212/11560810)

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
def paging_version = "3.1.0"

implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"
```

Comment: can you please see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69755212/11560810)