# Binding is not applying to a fragments associated with ViewStub

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-viewpager2, viewstub

I have the current problem. Right now I'm trying to lazy inflate bunch of fragments for better performance, which are part of a ViewPager. The only solution I found was the usage of ViewStub.
Here's where what I did so far:

```kotlin
abstract class ViewStubFragment: BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentViewStubBinding

    private var mSavedInstanceState: Bundle? = null
    private var hasInflated = false
    private var viewStub: ViewStub? = null
    private var visible = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentViewStubBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        viewStub = binding.fragmentViewStub.viewStub
        viewStub?.layoutResource = getViewStubLayoutResource()
        mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState

        if(visible && !hasInflated) {
            val inflatedView = viewStub?.inflate()
            if (inflatedView != null) {
                onCreateViewAfterViewStubInflated(inflatedView, mSavedInstanceState)
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    protected abstract fun onCreateViewAfterViewStubInflated(
        inflatedView: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    )

    @LayoutRes
    protected abstract fun getViewStubLayoutResource(): Int


    @CallSuper
    protected fun afterViewStubInflated(originalViewContainerWithViewStub: View?) {
        hasInflated = true
        if (originalViewContainerWithViewStub != null) {
            val progressBar = binding.progressBar
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        visible = true
        if (viewStub != null && !hasInflated) {
            val inflatedView = viewStub!!.inflate()
            onCreateViewAfterViewStubInflated(inflatedView, mSavedInstanceState)
            afterViewStubInflated(view)
        }
    }
```

The corresponding layout:

```kotlin
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"/>
        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/fragment_view_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

Part of the code from HomeFragment which I'm trying to lazily inflate:

```kotlin
class HomeFragment : ViewStubFragment() {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

........

    override fun onCreateViewAfterViewStubInflated(
        inflatedView: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        setDataBinding()
        observeLiveData()
    }

    override fun getViewStubLayoutResource(): Int {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root.sourceLayoutResId
    }
```

The problem is when `setDataBinding()` is called, the binding for some reason is not applied, thus Views like RecyclerView are not showing on the screen or click events aren not working. I have searched for hours but couldn't find solution related to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another hour of struggle I found a solution, not sure if it is the best possible.

```kotlin
        if(visible && !hasInflated) {
            inflatedViewBinding = binding.fragmentViewStub.binding
            val inflatedView = viewStub?.inflate()
            if (inflatedView != null) {
                onCreateViewAfterViewStubInflated(inflatedView, mSavedInstanceState, inflatedViewBinding)
            }
        }
```

I passed the stored in `ViewStubProxy` binding (associated with the inflated layout) as argument in `onCreateViewAfterViewStubInflated()` and then assign the HomeFragment binding to it.

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateViewAfterViewStubInflated(
        inflatedView: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
        binding: ViewDataBinding?
    ) {
        this.binding = binding as FragmentHomeBinding
        .......
    }
```

Comment: can you check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813808/11560810)