# How do I assert that a scrollable TabLayout is currently showing a certain tab?

Tags: android-espresso, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am displaying a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) and connecting it to a [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) object (by means of the [TabLayoutMediator](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayoutMediator) class). The [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) has a [tabMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout#setTabMode(int)) of [scrollable](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout#MODE_SCROLLABLE) and contains more tabs than can fit in the screen at once. I want to assert that a certain one of the tabs is visible and selected when my activity or fragment is rendered. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `Matcher` for the tabs:

```
fun withTab(title: String) = withTab(equalTo(title))

fun withTab(title: Matcher<String>): Matcher<View> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, TabView>(TabView::class.java) {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("with tab: ")
            title.describeTo(description)
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(item: TabView): Boolean {
            return title.matches(item.tab?.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Then to find if a tab is currently showing, you can conveniently do it with:

```
onView(withTab("tab text")).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()))
```

If you want to assert if a tab is currently selected, you can either adjust `matchesSafely` to work with `item.tab?.isSelected`, or simply create a new matcher.

However if you have more than one `TabLayout` on the screen, then you may need to composite your matcher with `isDescendantOfA` or `withParent`.

Comment: can you check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813808/11560810)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312053/1071320), I've defined `withTabText(text:)` and `isSelectedTab()` functions and my test's are now reading more fluently, as follows:

```
onView(withTabText("SomeText")).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()))
onView(withTabText("SomeText")).check(matches(isSelectedTab()))
```

The `isSelectedTab()` function is implemented as follows:

```
/**
 * @return A matcher that matches a [TabLayout.TabView] which is in the selected state.
 */
fun isSelectedTab(): Matcher<View> =
    object : BoundedMatcher<View, TabLayout.TabView>(TabLayout.TabView::class.java) {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("TabView is selected")
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(tabView: TabLayout.TabView): Boolean {
            return tabView.tab?.isSelected == true
        }
    }
```

The `withTabText(text:)` function is implemented as follows:

```
/**
 * @param text The text to match on.
 * @return A matcher that matches a [TabLayout.TabView] which has the given text.
 */
fun withTabText(text: String): Matcher<View> =
    object : BoundedMatcher<View, TabLayout.TabView>(TabLayout.TabView::class.java) {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("TabView with text $text")
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(tabView: TabLayout.TabView): Boolean {
            return text == tabView.tab?.text
        }
    }
```

I've added both of these functions to my collection of custom view matchers in the [android-test-utils](https://github.com/TazkiyaTech/android-test-utils) GitHub repo.

Comment: can you check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813808/11560810)