# Binding becomes when fragment is visible in ViewPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2, android-viewbinding

**Problem:**
I have a `ContainerFragment` in which there is a ViewPager. `CameraFragment` is being shown in this viewpager. The shutter button is in `ContainerFragment` and I'm using an interface to receive callback in CameraFragment when shutter button is clicked in order to click picture. When callback is received then I try to capture image and app crashes with error.

**Log:**

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: should never call auto-cleared-value get when it might not be available
            at com.example.chat.utils.services.AutoClearedValue.getValue(AutoClearedValue.kt:51)
            at com.example.chat.ui.base.BaseFragment.getBinding(BaseFragment.kt:41)
            at com.example.chat.ui.camera.camera.CameraFragment.captureImage(CameraFragment.kt:127)
    at com.example.chat.ui.camera.camera.CameraFragment.onShutterClicked(CameraFragment.kt:135) 
at com.example.chat.ui.camera.camerafragmentcontainer.CameraContainerFragment.handleShutterClick(CameraContainerFragment.kt:94)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue. The problem was that when I was initializing the interface I was creating an instance of CameraFragment() and again in viewpager a new instance was being created. so just passed the same instance in viewpager and the problem solved.

Comment: can you check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813808/11560810)