# Calling refresh method on paging data in jetpack compose not working correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

I'm using below paging source implementation to fetch data from network and observing it in composable via `collectAsLazyPagingItems()`. However, when calling `refresh()` method on this `LazyPagingItems`, it is not fetching data from `page 0` and instead fetch data from last fetched page number, which is resulting in no data to display. What's wrong here? Could it be because of `val page = params.key ?: 0` ?

```
class CommentDataSource(
    private val postId: Long,
    private val commentApi: CommentApi
) : PagingSource<Int, Comment>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Comment>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Comment> {
        return try {
            val page = params.key ?: 0
            val responseData = commentApi.getPostComments(
                postId = postId,
                page = page
            ).data

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = responseData.comments,
                prevKey = if (page == 0) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (!responseData.hasNextPage) null else responseData.currentPage + 1
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolve this issues by returning null in the `getRefreshKey()` method

Comment: can you please see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69755212/11560810)

Comment: @vivekmodi how does your issue help to solve the problem here?

Comment: Do you have same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue for me.
Use this in your PagingSource

```kotlin
override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, DiscountModel>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }
```