# How to pass MutableLiveData <String> from function to Pager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-paging, android-paging-3

I am trying to use my search function with Paging 3. I checked my addQuery() function and my _repoQuery value is not null there when I do a search. But when I try to pass the value to the Pager {}, it is always null. I know that because it always brings up a list of books corresponding to the default value ("flowers"). Does anyone know how I can pass my _repoQuery value to the Pager {} when I do a search?

```
class MainViewModel () : ViewModel() {

    // Queries
    private val _repoQuery = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    private val _filter = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val reusableQuery = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    private val repo = Repo

    fun addFilter(filter: String?) {
        _filter.value = filter
    }

    fun addQuery(query: String) {
        _repoQuery.value = query // Here _repoQuery.value exists
        reusableQuery.value = _repoQuery.value
    }

    val books: Flow<PagingData<Volume>> = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 40)) {
        BookListSource(repo, bookFilter = _filter.value, query = _repoQuery.value?:"flowers")
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope) // Here _repoQuery.value is null
}
```

**Solution**

This is what worked in the end:

```
val repoQuery = _repoQuery.switchMap {
        liveData {
            emit(Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 40)) {
                BookListSource(repo, bookFilter = _filter.value, query = _repoQuery.value)
            }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope))
        }
    }
```

My understanding is that the liveData is emitting fresh results as they arrive...

Answer (score 1):

Its null because your `filter`/`query` don't have any values when when the `Pager` is created. You need to remake the `Pager` when you change those values because the `BookListSource` you gave it is no longer valid. This isn't the prettiest thing in the world, but it should get you started.

```
//Make it once at the start to avoid lateinit 
var books : Flow<PagingData<Volume>> = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 40)) {
          BookListSource(repo, bookFilter = _filter.value, query = _repoQuery.value?:"flowers")
     }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope) 

fun addFilter(filter: String?) {
    _filter.value = filter
    //filter changes so the BookListSource needs to be different
    books = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 40)) {
         BookListSource(repo, bookFilter = _filter.value, query = _repoQuery.value?:"flowers")
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope) 
}

fun addQuery(query: String) {
    _repoQuery.value = query // Here _repoQuery.value exists
    reusableQuery.value = _repoQuery.value
    //query changes so the BookListSource needs to be different
    books = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 40)) {
         BookListSource(repo, bookFilter = _filter.value, query = _repoQuery.value?:"flowers")
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! This didn't work but wrapping the code in liveData did the trick.

Comment: Hey @avalerio can you please see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69755212/11560810)