# How to collect flow data after view is complete initialise in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow

Hey I am working on Kotlin flow. I am working in ViewPager2 with Paging 3 Library. I am getting some bug which caused indexing issue in ViewPager2. Someone suggested me use `lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated` but it not working correctly. According to this answer [The core issue is that are starting collection on Paging before ViewPager is ready to start binding the items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813808/11560810). I tried this solution, but it didn't work well. I want to dig deeply, what the issue of this logic. I added my project link as well [Github](https://github.com/vivek-modi/ViewPagerExample)

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
  viewModel.dataList.collectLatest {
    adapter.submitData(it)
  }
}
```

Comment: could you explain more what is the bug you faced ?

Comment: @HussienFahmy thanks for replying me. The core issue is that I am starting collection on Paging before ViewPager is ready to start binding the items as per given [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813808/11560810). Can you check the given link

Comment: @HussienFahmy this [link](https://youtu.be/FxMtgA-U79w) I attached video link. The problem is my view causing indexing issue. i.e. my view is not inflated properly and flow collecting starts. So i need something to untill view is inflated the collection will not start.

Comment: are you using dataBinding ?

Comment: No viewbinding @HussienFahmy

Comment: @HussienFahmy Can you please check out github link. This is my sample project