# How can I correctly use custom PagingSource with PagingDataAdapter, on local data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3

**The Problem**

I have locally-generated data that I need to display in a `RecyclerView`. I tried to use a custom `PagingSource` with `PagingDataAdapter` to reduce the amount of data in memory, but I get visual effects when I invalidate the data, for example if I insert or delete one item:

- when the visible items belong to 2 different "pages", many unchanged items flash as if they had been modified
- if all the visible items belong to the same page, everything is fine. Only the inserted / deleted item shows an animation.

I took an example application referenced by Google's doc ([PagingSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/PagingSample)) to test the concept. The original with Room does not show artefacts, but my modified version with custom `PagingSource` does.

The code generated and used by Room is too complicated to see any difference that would explain the issue.

My data must be locally-generated, I can't use Room as a work-around to display them.

**My question**

How can I properly define a `PagingSource` for my local data, and use it with PagingDataAdapter without visual glitches?

Optionally, how can I know when data is discarded (so I can discard my local data as well)?

**Code excerpts and details**

The full example project is hosted here: https://github.com/blueglyph/PagingSampleModified

Here is the data:

```kotlin
    private val _data = ArrayMap<Int, Cheese>()
    val data = MutableLiveData <Map<Int, Cheese>>(_data)
    val sortedData = data.map { data -> data.values.sortedBy { it.name.lowercase() } }
```

and the `PagingSource`. I'm using key = item position. I have tried with key = page number, each page containing 30 items (10 are visible), but it does not change anything.

```kotlin
    private class CheeseDataSource(val dao: CheeseDaoLocal, val pageSize: Int): PagingSource<Int, Cheese>() {
        fun max(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if (a > b) a else b

        override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Cheese>): Int? {
            val lastPos = dao.count() - 1
            val key = state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
                val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
                anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(pageSize)?.coerceAtMost(lastPos) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(pageSize)?.coerceAtLeast(0)
            }
            return key
        }

        override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Cheese> {
            val pageNumber = params.key ?: 0
            val count = dao.count()
            val data = dao.allCheesesOrdName().drop(pageNumber).take(pageSize)
            return LoadResult.Page(
                data = data,
                prevKey = if (pageNumber > 0) max(0, pageNumber - pageSize) else null,
                nextKey = if (pageNumber + pageSize < count) pageNumber + pageSize else null
            )
        }
    }
```

The `Flow` on `PagingData` is created in the view model:

```kotlin
    val pageSize = 30
    var dataSource: PagingSource<Int, Cheese>? = null
    val allCheeses: Flow<PagingData<CheeseListItem>> = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = pageSize,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
            maxSize = 90
        )
    ) {
        dataSource = dao.getDataSource(pageSize)
        dataSource!!
    }.flow
        .map { pagingData -> pagingData.map { cheese -> CheeseListItem.Item(cheese) } }
```

with `dao.getDataSource(pageSize)` returning the `CheeseDataSource` shown above.

and in the activity, data pages are collected and submitted:

```kotlin
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.allCheeses.collectLatest { adapter.submitData(it) }
        }
```

When the data is modified, an observer triggers an invalidation:

```kotlin
        dao.sortedData.observeForever {
            dataSource?.invalidate()
        }
```

The scrolling and loading of pages is fine, the only problems come when `invalidate` is used and when items from 2 pages are displayed simultaneously.

The adapter is classic:

```kotlin
class CheeseAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<CheeseListItem, CheeseViewHolder>(diffCallback) {
...
    companion object {
        val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CheeseListItem>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CheeseListItem, newItem: CheeseListItem): Boolean {
                return if (oldItem is CheeseListItem.Item && newItem is CheeseListItem.Item) {
                    oldItem.cheese.id == newItem.cheese.id
                } else if (oldItem is CheeseListItem.Separator && newItem is CheeseListItem.Separator) {
                    oldItem.name == newItem.name
                } else {
                    oldItem == newItem
                }
            }
            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CheeseListItem, newItem: CheeseListItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
...
```

**What I have tried** (among many other things)

- use LiveData instead of Flow
- using / removing the cache on the Flow
- removing the observers and invalidating directly in insert/delete functions to make the code more direct
- instead of key = position, using key = page number (0, 1, 2, ...) with each page containing pageSize=30 items

At this point, I'm not sure anymore that paging-3 is meant to be used for custom data. I'm observing so many operations for a simple insert/delete, such as 2000-4000 compare ops in the adapter, reloading 3 pages of data, ... that using `ListAdapter` directly on my data and doing the load/unload manually seems a better option.

Comment: Hey, have you been able to find a fix for this? I am using SQLDelight OffsetQueryPagingSource and seeing UI jank on animation when removing an item from RV, which triggers DB updates multiple times in a short period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE July 2022**

**There are some problems with paging-3. The most noticeable ones are**

- **failure to properly load the dataset when using an initial position** with `initialKey` (see [initial_key](https://github.com/blueglyph/PagingSampleModified/tree/initial_key) branch)
- **failure to properly jump to another position** with `scrollToPositionWithOffset` or similar function (see [test_scroll](https://github.com/blueglyph/PagingSampleModified/tree/test_scroll) branch)

`getRefreshKey` function is called with weird (sometimes negative) values of `anchorPosition`, and load is called multiple times to load unnecessary data - sometimes loading iteratively every page from the end or from the beginning.

I believe the same problem can be observed when the PagingSource is generated by Room.

=> In short, it can only be used if you need to display the top items first, and if you don't need to jump to a particular position (seeing other items is only done when the user manually scrolls through the list). A fix is on the way but it could take time; it's still only alpha and compiles for a specific set of library versions / SDK.

You'll find another, simpler algorithm for `getRefreshKey` and `load` in the mentioned branches, in CheeseDao.kt.

**End of update**

---

I finally found out a possible solution, though I'm not sure it will work if the Paging-3 library is updated. I don't know yet if the behaviour explained above is due to bugs / limitations in the Paging-3 components or if that's just a bad explanation in the reference documentation, or something I missed entirely.

**I. Work-around for the glitch issue.**

1. In `PagingConfig`, we **must** have `enablePlaceholders = true` or it simply won't work correctly. With `false` I'm observing the scrollbar jumping on each `load` operation when scrolling up/down, and inserting items at the end will make all items glitch on the display, then the list will jump all the way to the top.
2. The logic in `getRefreshKey` and `load`, as shown in Google's guide and reference documentation, is naive and will not work with custom data. I had to modify them as follows (modifications have been pushed in the github example):

```kotlin
        override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Cheese>): Int? = state.anchorPosition

        override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Cheese> {
            data class Args(
                var start: Int = 0, var size: Int = 0, var prevKey: Int? = null, var nextKey: Int? = null,
                var itemsBefore: Int = UNDEF, var itemsAfter: Int = UNDEF
            )
            val pos = params.key ?: 0
            val args = Args()
            when (params) {
                is LoadParams.Append -> {
                    args.start = pos
                    args.prevKey = params.key
                    //args.nextKey = if (args.start < count) min(args.start + params.loadSize, count) else null
                    args.nextKey = if (args.start + params.loadSize < count) args.start + params.loadSize else null
                }
                is LoadParams.Prepend -> {
                    args.start = max(pos - pageSize, 0)
                    args.prevKey = if (args.start > 0) args.start else null
                    args.nextKey = params.key
                }
                is LoadParams.Refresh -> {
                    args.start = max((pos - params.loadSize/2)/pageSize*pageSize, 0)
                    args.prevKey = if (args.start > 0) args.start else null
                    args.nextKey = if (args.start + params.loadSize < count) min(args.start + params.loadSize, count - 1) else null
                }
            }
            args.size = min(params.loadSize, count - args.start)
            if (params is LoadParams.Refresh) {
                args.itemsBefore = args.start
                args.itemsAfter = count - args.size - args.start
            }
            val source = dao.allCheesesOrdName()
            val data = source.drop(args.start).take(args.size)
            if (params.key == null && data.count() == 0) {
                return LoadResult.Error(Exception("Empty"))
            }
            val result = LoadResult.Page(
                data = data,
                prevKey = args.prevKey,
                nextKey = args.nextKey,
                itemsBefore = args.itemsBefore,
                itemsAfter = args.itemsAfter
            )
            return result
        }
```

I had to deduce that from the behaviour of Room-generated PagingSource, by inserting a wrapper between the DAO code and the view model to observe the `params` and `LoadResult` values.

Notes

- The commented line in `LoadParam.Append` mimics the Room-generated code behaviour, which is slightly incorrect when loading the last page. It makes the Pager loads an empty page at the end, which is not a serious issue but triggers unnecessary operations in the whole chain.
- I'm not sure about the `Refresh` case, it was hard to induce any logic from Room's code behaviour. Here I'm placing the `params.key` position in the middle of the loaded range (`params.loadSize` items). At worst it will append data in a 2nd load operation.

**II. Predicting the discarded data**

This should be possible from the `params` given to the `load` function. In a simplified heuristic (the ranges must be min/max'ed to get actual indices):

```
LoadParams.Append  -> loads [key .. key+loadSize[, so discard [key-maxSize..key-maxSize+loadSize[
LoadParams.Prepend -> loads [key-loadSize .. key[, do discard [key-loadSize+maxSize..key+maxSize[
LoadParams.Refresh -> discard what is not reloaded
```

The `Args.start .. Args.start + Args.size` in the code above can be used as the range which is kept, from there it is easy to deduce what is discarded.

Comment: Hey can you look this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69755212/11560810)